# Selenium - select option from dropdown, slow run time

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, select, dropdown

I'm using Selenium and python via a Jupiter Notebook, to log in to a website, second login screen asks for 3 characters from my chosen country “Singapore”, (not actually my country, I changed it for this question). I do not know which three characters it will ask for, example, 1st, 4th and 6th, or 2nd, 3rd and 8th, …. etc

So I used “if statements” to see which characters it asked me and select the appropriate character.

But this code is very slow, it takes up to 3 minutes for Selenium to pick all three characters.

Can the run time be fast? Or does a fast run time require another approach than the if statements?

Btw the first select box is always instant, it's the second and third that take minutes to get filled.

```
if driver.find_elements("id", "characterPick1"):
    select = Select(driver.find_element("id", "characterPick1"))
    select.select_by_visible_text(’S’)

if driver.find_elements("id", "characterPick2"):
    select = Select(driver.find_element("id", "characterPick2"))
    select.select_by_visible_text(‘I’)

if driver.find_elements("id", "characterPick3"):
    select = Select(driver.find_element("id", "characterPick3"))
    select.select_by_visible_text(’N’)

if driver.find_elements("id", "characterPick4"):
    select = Select(driver.find_element("id", "characterPick4"))
    select.select_by_visible_text(‘G’)

if driver.find_elements("id", "characterPick5"):
    select = Select(driver.find_element("id", "characterPick5"))
    select.select_by_visible_text(‘A’)

if driver.find_elements("id", "characterPick6"):
    select = Select(driver.find_element("id", "characterPick6"))
    select.select_by_visible_text(‘P’)

if driver.find_elements("id", "characterPick7"):
    select = Select(driver.find_element("id", "characterPick7"))
    select.select_by_visible_text(‘O’)

if driver.find_elements("id", "characterPick8"):
    select = Select(driver.find_element("id", "characterPick8"))
    select.select_by_visible_text(‘R’)

if driver.find_elements("id", "characterPick9"):
    select = Select(driver.find_element("id", "characterPick9"))
    select.select_by_visible_text(‘E’)
```